# How can I install virt-v2v on Ubuntu Focal?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Here are instructions for Ubuntu 22.04: https://installati.one/install-virt-v2v-ubuntu-22-04

This link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libguestfs/+bug/1927863 says that it used to be in `libguestfs-tools` and has been moved in Fedora, but I have not been able to locate `virt-v2v` for Ubuntu Focal 20.4

Answer (score 2):

virt-v2v virtual-to-virtual machine converter is in the universe repository on Ubuntu 22.04. To install virt-v2v on Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install virt-v2v
```

The easiest thing to do in this situation is to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I am not yet ready to tackle upgrading my 20.4 system

Comment: virt-v2v has so many critical unmet dependencies that you will break your package management and maybe the whole operating system trying to install it any other way, so you really have no options except to upgrade to 22.04 or else give up and don't install virt-v2v.

Comment: Thanks for the (brutal) answer. I got another computer and installed 22.04 on it.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu Focal, virt-v2v is part of libguestfs-tools package according to [this page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/virt-v2v.1.html) So you need to install libguestfs-tools to get virt-v2v

```
sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools
```

Tested on my 20.04 Ubuntu server and it works.

Comment: The caveat is, the virt-v2v still old version that not works with ESXI7.0 and above